# Android add jar to custom library

Tags: android, jar

I have made an android project in eclipse. This project has a library project:
the library project (marked with "is library") has included a jar file.
this library project does a lot of stuff with the use of the jar file.
in code everything is fine.

The problem is that the reference to the jar file doesn't exist anymore when it is compiled and installed to my phone.

When i add the jarfile also to my base project. Then the program works.
However, i don't believe that this is the right solution.
So what does i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library jar you used in your Android Library Project must be manually added to the dependent application project's build path, not the Android library project build path itself, check out API [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#considerations)

Comment: Serious? This is stupid, but indeed, i see. So what i did wasn't wrong. You should say that if the class library has a link to an jar that the class library itself will hold that jar file. But i will keep the link twice to the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a libs folder to your project

Then, add the jar to the folder and right click on the .jar file and go to Build Path, and select Add To Path or Build To Path. This way the library will be a part of your project. This should help.

Comment: what are you getting in the logcat?

Comment: Found on the net:

A library project will not be compiled into its own apk file

A library project can use other jar files

My library is installed sepratly on my divice. It puts an shortcut in the app menu

Comment: i see, but can't post it here... error is: NoClassDefFoundError: and than a class in the jar file

Comment: eclipse generete automatic a jar file when "is library" is checked. It only includes src and gen folder. I can add the new created libs folder by properties->javabuildpath->sources however this will adds the jar file and not the content of the jarfile.